# How to modify Payment Interface in POS (Odoo 10)

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-10, point-of-sale

I am currently struggling in POS on Odoo. I am new in modifying the front-end of Odoo using Javascript.

I already look at different module but I am confuse and I already searched it but I found the related problems and solutions in the older version of Odoo which is version 8 and 9.

All I want to do is to add the "Care of" button below the "Cash (USD)" button in the payment interface and add some functions.

[image: payment interface]

but

it appears in left pane above the numpad pane.

using this line of codes.

pos_custom/static/src/js

pos_custom.js

```js
odoo.define('pos_custom.pos_custom', function (require) {
"use strict";

var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');

var careOfButton = screens.ActionButtonWidget.extend({
    template: 'careOfButton',

    button_click: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.gui.show_popup('selection',{
            'title': 'Welcome to JS world',

        });
    },

});

    screens.define_action_button({
        'name': 'careOf',
        'widget': careOfButton,
    });
});
```

pos_custom/static/src/xml

pos_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

    <t t-name="careOfButton">
        <div class='control-button'>
            <i class='fa fa-tag' /> Care of
        </div>
    </t>

</templates>
```

[image: wrong output]

Please help me. Any suggestions/ possible solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inherit the template `PaymentScreen-Paymentmethods` and place your button after all payment methods, your template should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" inherit_id="point_of_sale.template">

<t t-extend="PaymentScreen-Paymentmethods">
    <t t-jquery="div[class='paymentmethods']" t-operation="after">
        <div class='control-button'>
            <i class='fa fa-tag' /> Care of
        </div>
    </t>
</t>
```

For jquery selector take a look the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/).

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Comment: how can I add functions on my button?

Comment: I already solve my problem before you answer it but anw thank you. Our answer is almost the same

Comment: Post yout other problem in other question.

Comment: Please I have the same problem can you post your answer